# Script to adjust font-style based on date also overwrites formulas in cells

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a spreadsheet for sheduling, and to keep things clean I'm using a script that will change a rows font style based on the date, so if the date is already passed the font will become italics, greyed out, and have line-through. The script works great, but it overwrites all formulas in the spreadsheet when used. Is there a way to edit the formula so it doesn't affect certain cells? (it should do nothing to rows that are for dates that haven't happened yet).

Here's the script I'm using:

```
function formatOnDate() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sh.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var color = '#AAA';// value you want
  var style = 'italic';// value you want
  var line = 'line-through';// value you want
  var fontColors = range.getFontColors();// get all font colors
  var fontLines = range.getFontLines();// lines
  var fontStyles = range.getFontStyles();//style
  var today = new Date();// include today in sheet

  //var today = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1));// exclude today... uncomment the one you use
  for(var n=1 ; n<data.length ; n++){ // start on row 2 so that headers are not changed
    if(data[n][0] < today){
      for(var c in data[0]){
        fontColors[n][c]=color;//set format
        fontLines[n][c]=line;//set format
        fontStyles[n][c]=style;//set format

      }
    }
  }
  //sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).clear();
  // now update sheet with new data and style
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data).setFontColors(fontColors).setFontLines(fontLines).setFontStyles(fontStyles);
}
```

Is it possible to adjust the font styles without overwriting a formula in a cell? Is it possible to not affect rows for dates that haven't happened yet? If not, is it possible to not affect certain columns? (Column N-Q are the columns that have formulas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, `data` is not modified. And also the number of array length of `fontColors`, `fontLines` and `fontStyles` are not modified. So how about this modification?

This modified script doesn't overwrite the data. Only FontColors, FontLines and FontStyles are reflected to `range`. So formulas of each cell isn't affected.

#### From :

```
sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data).setFontColors(fontColors).setFontLines(fontLines).setFontStyles(fontStyles);
```

#### To :

```
range.setFontColors(fontColors).setFontLines(fontLines).setFontStyles(fontStyles);
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.